# Customizing Date range filter for Google Chart

Tags: php, jquery, json, google-visualization

I am facing an issue while implementing `ChartRangeFilter` and `CategoryFilter` in Google Charts.I am plotting a Line Chart with date range field on x-axis. I have month and year data hence why I am trying to visualize data by using month and year range filter.

One approach I have found is to convert date field data e.g. `2011-01-31` to numeric `201101` in MySQL database and then sending it to view using AJAX/JSON approach.Then formatting it to date and inserting it into Google's data table.

I have referenced this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YyYsN/2/) but data is hard-coded and I need to implement the same logic for my JSON data and I am not able to access JSON data in my jQuery to format it according to my requirement.

Is there any solution or approach available so that I can use month and year range filter to visualize month & year data in Google Charts using my Laravel 5.1 application?

**Code snippet:**

```
function drawChart() 
{
    var jsonData =  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'get_salesthree',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
                    }).responseText;
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();


    dataTable.addColumn('date', 'YearMonth');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Chevrolet');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Datsun');
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Fiat');
     var i = 1;

$.each(jsonData, function () {

    var year = this.Date.substring(0, 4);
    var month = this.Date.substring(4);

    //var dataItem = [new Date(year, month), this.articles];

    var dataItem = [new Date(year, month), this.Chevrolet, this.Datsun, this.Fiat, this.Ford, this.Honda, this.Hyundai, this.Mahindra, this.Maruti, this.Nissan, this.Renault, this.Skoda, this.Tata, this.Toyota, this.Volkswagen];
    dataTable.addRow(dataItem);

});
```